# Docker from micromamba base image is hanging at " Transaction starting" step when installing packages on Apple Silicon (osx-arm64)

Tags: docker, macos, anaconda, apple-silicon, micromamba

I'm trying to build docker images on my MacBook Pro which is using a M2 processor.  I've created images from this Dockerfile several times on my previous MacBook Pro which used an Intel processor.

I'm currently running iTerm2 w/ Rosetta to simulate an Intel processor.

```
$ arch
i386
```

Here is my build command:

```
docker build --build-arg ENV_NAME=${ENV_NAME} -t ${TAG} -f Dockerfile ../../
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# v2024.3.10
# =================================
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mambaorg/micromamba:latest

ARG ENV_NAME

SHELL ["/usr/local/bin/_dockerfile_shell.sh"]

WORKDIR /tmp/

# Data
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/input
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/output
RUN mkdir -p /volumes/database

# Retrieve VEBA repository
RUN mkdir -p veba/
USER $MAMBA_USER
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./install/ veba/install/
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./bin/ veba/bin/
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./VERSION veba/VERSION
COPY --chown=$MAMBA_USER:$MAMBA_USER ./LICENSE veba/LICENSE

# Fix: 
# critical libmamba Download error (28) Timeout was reached
# [https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64/blast-2.13.0-hf3cf87c_0.tar.bz2]
# Operation too slow. Less than 30 bytes/sec transferred the last 60 seconds

ARG MAMBA_NO_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT=1

# Build .condarc
RUN echo "channel_priority: flexible" >> ~/.condarc
RUN echo "channels:" >> ~/.condarc
RUN echo "  - conda-forge" >> ~/.condarc
RUN echo "  - bioconda" >> ~/.condarc
RUN echo "  - jolespin" >> ~/.condarc

# Install dependencies
RUN micromamba install -y -n base -f veba/install/environments/${ENV_NAME}.yml && \
    micromamba clean -a -y -f

# Add environment scripts to environment bin
RUN cp -rf veba/bin/* /opt/conda/bin/ && \
    ln -sf /opt/conda/bin/scripts/*.py /opt/conda/bin/ && \
    ln -sf /opt/conda/bin/scripts/*.r /opt/conda/bin/

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/_entrypoint.sh"]
```

I've also tried this in terminal without Rosetta:

```
$ arch
arm64
```

The weirdest part about this is that I was able to build an image from this [conda environment yaml](https://github.com/jolespin/veba/blob/main/install/environments/VEBA-annotate_env.yml) last night but now it's not working. The full list of Docker images I'm building are using the following yaml files: https://github.com/jolespin/veba/tree/main/install/environments

**Does anyone have any idea on how I can build these Docker images on Apple Silicon?**

Comment: Paring this down to only the `RUN micromamba install ...` command  on the linked YAML (with no extra `.condarc` manipulation), it solves and installs fine for me. I run the `docker build` in a native (`osx-arm64`) Terminal and it correctly produces a `linux-amd64` image. Build time is ~1 min with Docker allocated 8 cores and 8GB memory on an M1. There are some lock access warnings, indicating the 8 cores is probably overkill, but seems innocuous.

Comment: Interesting so you think the condarc might be causing the hanging transaction? I’ll give this a try tomorrow morning.

Comment: @merv I tried running this over night without rosetta (osx-arm64) and I got the same results: https://i.imgur.com/rVYO6YM.png Transaction starting has been going for 33968.8s and counting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to do 3 things if you encounter this issue:

1. Use `FROM --platform=linux/amd64`
2. Open your terminal or iTerm using Rosetta:

[image]

3. Go to `Docker > Settings > General > Use Rosetta for x86_64/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon` (Turn it on):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure (2) is necessary - I did have VirtioFS enabled and the "*Use Rosetta...*" option checked when I built the image from a native Terminal.